# Unable to access 126 GB Volume

Tags: 13.04

In first place, sorry for my english. After that, i want to say that im a newbie, its the first time i have used Ubuntu.

I have this message error when i tried to access mi 126GB volume:

[image]

I looked for info in this page, but any post talked about that, or i didnt found it (maybe i didnt understand, its possible too).

The idea was recovery some info of my pc (Windows dont reach at desktop) through Ubuntu for copypaste all interesting files to a HDD. Later, reinstall Windows. So, i dont know if this message error is common or not, and if it has any possible solution.

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my english, again. Im from Spain, i had very bad english teachers at school :P.

Comment: It looks like an Input/Output error, which could be caused by a billion things.  It looks like the partition isn't mountable, which could suggest a problem with the disk itself, or just a broken partition, and the only way to really fix that is to boot into a Windows recovery mode and run a `chkdisk /f`

Comment: Check the drive's SMART status in the disk utility; it is probably dieing.

Answer (score 0):

The disk may or may not be mounted another issue I found if it is a blank HDD is to format it to a ext4 format using a program such as GParted