# Unable to access 64gb volume - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mount, micro-sd

I'm unable to mount Sandisk 64GB SDXC card.

This error shown while connecting using my phone.

[image: This]

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296484/unable-to-access-126-gb-volume), [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/506200/ububntu-14-04-unable-to-mount-63-gb-volume) and [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2033767) links, but unable to find any solution.

I've tried the below commands to install the exfat,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install exfat-utils fuse-exfat
```

But below error displayed in terminal,

```
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
fuse-exfat : Depends: fuse-utils (>= 2.7) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no need to add extra repo. If you are using Ubuntu 14.04, `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` packages are present in Universe repository.

Enable it (if it is not enabled)  using

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Update your software list using

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install it  using

```
  sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But is it the fuse-exfat or exfat-fuse?

Comment: It is [exfat-fuse](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/exfat-fuse).