# Micro SD Card slot not working on Lenovo N22 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, ssd, sd-card

I have installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo N22, but am having problems with the microSD card reader. the system does not recognise it at at.

This is the result from `lsusb`:

```
danna@danna-Lenovo-N22:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b582 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
danna@danna-Lenovo-N22:~$
```

and `lspci`:

```
danna@danna-Lenovo-N22:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev 21)
00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc (rev 21)
00:12.0 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 2296 (rev 21)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 22a3 (rev 21)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22cc (rev 21)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)
danna@danna-Lenovo-N22:~$
```

I can't even work out if the microSD drive is there at all. 
The machine is very small, I think the internal drive is just some sort of SD card.

I can use the USB drive fine (I have a problem with one specific USB but others work ok).

Answer (score 0):

Some Silicon Motion adapters seem to be defective when used with large SD cards.  I am thinking it's a SDXC (or SDHC) protocol issue so that the older adapters have code that is incompatible with newer cards (despite the fact that this is not supposed to happen).

See:  [Mount problem with 64gb microSDXC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558594/mount-problem-with-64gb-microsdxc/1021362#1021362)