# Error: Unable to access "128 GB Volume"

Tags: sd-card, storage

I keep getting asked to explain how this is different from another post but even that other post is unresolved. If that post did not lead to success, how would my issue be resolved?

I read and followed the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528450/unable-to-access-64gb-volume-ubuntu-14-04) using the code `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils`

Previously my Files page showed the 128 GB SD card but showed the error message: unable to access... as per the title, ending in:

> unknown filesystem type 'exfat'

After restarting the computer, files doesn't seem to see the SD card at all. It doesn't show up in the files sidebar. See screenshot with original error code and SD card in sidebar.

Running Ubuntu 18.04

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ubuntu 18.04 not mount exFat 2TB even after installing exfat-fuse exfat-utils](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057423/ubuntu-18-04-not-mount-exfat-2tb-even-after-installing-exfat-fuse-exfat-utils)

Comment: But that issue was unresolved it appears

Comment: It suggest to install exfat tools: `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` .. have you done that ?

Comment: Yes, I posted that exact code in my first message

Comment: Ok, so here is the result of following the 2nd piece of advice on that thread. As you can see, no result. And there is nothing more on that thread... 'user@zach:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:relan/exfat
[sudo] password for user: 
 tag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~relan/+archive/ubuntu/exfat
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

'Error reading https://keyserver.ubuntu.com/pks/lookup?op=get&options=mr&exact=on&search=0xtag:launchpad.net:2008:redacted: Not Found''